# correct verb form of "to be''

Tags: tense

I have made up the similar sentences below.

(1) I have shopped at ABC Supermarket before. Its merchandise **is** very well-organized and its staff **is** nice.

(2) I have shopped at ABC Supermarket before. Its merchandise **was** very well-organized and its staff **was** nice.

I am not sure whether I should use the present or past tense of "to be" in the similar versions of my example.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to say.

If you want to imply that things are good today because your past experience was good, then the present tense is perfect. (Presumably, the past experience was fairly recent.)

If you want to affirm that things used to be good because your past experience was good, then the past tense is perfect. (Presumably, the past experience was not fairly recent.)

Grammar does not control here; intended meaning determines the grammar.

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent explanation.